# Is it possible to control which calendars Outlook uses to share free/busy time?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, icloud

I have an Exchange account with my company, and I'm using the iCloud add-in.

I have chosen to share my free/busy time with my co-workers, and have opted to share the name of the appointment as well, not just "free/busy" status.

I don't want my iCloud calendar to affect my free/busy time, because it is a shared calendar with my wife. What ends up happening is her hair appointment blocks my work hours, and I don't want the details of my iCloud appointments visible to my co-workers.

My work-around was to manually block off time in my work calendar with a dummy appointment to match the appointments in my iCloud calendar that were actually mine, and not my wife's. But I've now found out that my iCloud calendar details are being shared with my work, and I feel that's inappropriate.

So, is my only option to not share any details other than the free/busy status, and then edit of my wife's iCloud appointments to be shown as "free"?

**Update**
Tuns out I may have been falsing equating the free/busy time (and hence calendar information) with the "availability" information that shows up alongside someone's name when sending them an email. I'll do more investigation and see what I find. Marking solved for now.

Comment: Something looks very strange in your setup, can you please explain that in more words? If you for Example have an Outlook and Exchange company mailfile, you can control what is seen by your workmaded. If you then use an additional account (e.g. Google Mail) you can share only that with your wife... However it looks like you are running some kind of strange setup which needs more details.

Comment: Sure thing. I have an iCloud calendar that I share with my wife is configured in Outlook. I don't share my exchange calendar with my wife, but I do opt to share appointment names along with my free/busy times with my workmates. The iCloud calendar appeared to be affecting my free/busy time being shared with my workmates. I've edited my question to reflect a recent discovery.

Answer (score 0):

What triggered this was that my availability was showing us "busy" next to my contact details in an email, which got me thinking iCloud was affecting my "free/busy" time. In fact, it appears that these may be separate things. Marking closed for now until I do more research into the issue.